# Postfix service enabled but won't start on reboot

Tags: systemd, opensuse, postfix, services

The `postfix` service won't start after rebooting the system. We are using our own custom Linux OS based on OpenSuse 12.1 and recently verification departement has found that the `/var` repository is getting bigger and bigger due to unsend mail in the maildrop queue of `postfix`.

Who send those mails ? We have some applications that share some logs between systems.

I was looking over different kind of forum for my answer without any success.

After rebbot :

```
$systemctl status postfix.service
postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled)
          Active: inactive (dead)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/postfix.service
```

I found here [Postfix doesn't start on reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/667689/postfix-doesnt-start-on-reboot) that the problem can be a possible conflict with `sendmail`. To make sure that `sendmail` program is well link with `postfix` :

```
$ ldd /usr/sbin/sendmail
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa25ff000)
        libpostfix-global.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpostfix-global.so.1 (0x00007fdb174d2000)
        libpostfix-util.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpostfix-util.so.1 (0x00007fdb1729a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdb16f0a000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdb16d06000)
        libdb-4.8.so => /usr/lib64/libdb-4.8.so (0x00007fdb1698a000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fdb16772000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdb1770b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdb16555000)
```

I also check in `/var/log/messages` and there's not any information about `sendmail` or even `postfix` failure.

Let's start the service :

```
$ systemctl start postfix.service
$ systemctl status postfix.service
postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled)
          Active: active (running) since Sat, 28 Jan 2017 21:49:37 +0300; 41s ago
         Process: 3450 ExecStartPost=/etc/postfix/system/cond_slp register (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 3444 ExecStartPost=/etc/postfix/system/wait_qmgr 60 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 3368 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 3366 ExecStartPre=/etc/postfix/system/update_chroot (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 3363 ExecStartPre=/bin/echo Starting mail service (Postfix) (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        Main PID: 3443 (master)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/postfix.service
                  ├ 3443 /usr/lib/postfix/master
                  ├ 3445 pickup -l -t fifo -u
                  ├ 3446 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
                  ├ 3447 cleanup -z -t unix -u
                  ├ 3466 trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u
                  ├ 3467 local -t unix
                  ├ 3468 local -t unix
                  └ 3469 local -t unix
```

Good. Reboot the system and the service turn to *inactive(dead)*. Returning to `/var/log` I found this file `mail.warn`

```
$ cat mail.info
Jan 28 03:13:55 msx postfix/postfix-script[2527]: warning: not owned by group maildrop: /usr/sbin/postqueue
Jan 28 03:13:55 msx postfix/postfix-script[2528]: warning: not owned by group maildrop: /usr/sbin/postdrop
Jan 28 03:13:55 msx postfix/postfix-script[2530]: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postqueue
Jan 28 03:13:55 msx postfix/postfix-script[2531]: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postdrop
Jan 28 21:49:37 msx postfix/postfix-script[3430]: warning: not owned by group maildrop: /usr/sbin/postqueue
Jan 28 21:49:37 msx postfix/postfix-script[3431]: warning: not owned by group maildrop: /usr/sbin/postdrop
Jan 28 21:49:37 msx postfix/postfix-script[3434]: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postqueue
Jan 28 21:49:37 msx postfix/postfix-script[3435]: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postdrop
```

I don't know if this can't help to resolve my problem.

**Extra informations**

Inside the `postfix.service` file :

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/postfix.service
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Requires=var-run.mount nss-lookup.target network.target remote-fs.target syslog.target time-sync.target
After=var-run.mount nss-lookup.target network.target remote-fs.target syslog.target time-sync.target
After=amavis.service mysql.service cyrus.service ldap.service openslp.service ypbind.service
Before=mail-transfer-agent.target
Conflicts=sendmail.service exim.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
ExecStartPre=-/bin/echo 'Starting mail service (Postfix)'
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/postfix
ExecStartPre=/etc/postfix/system/update_chroot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start
ExecStartPost=/etc/postfix/system/wait_qmgr 60
ExecStartPost=/etc/postfix/system/cond_slp register
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postfix reload
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postfix flush
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop
ExecStopPost=/etc/postfix/system/cond_slp deregister

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

List all services after rebooting without starting the `postfix` service.

```
$systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
...
klog.service              disabled
klogd.service             masked
ldconfig.service          masked
loadmodules.service       masked
local.service             static
localfs.service           static
openhpid.service          enabled
postfix.service           enabled
postgresql.service        static
poweroff.service          static
proc.service              masked
...
```

Since we are running on OpenSuse 12.1 based OS, `journalctl` was not introduced yet into `systemd`

### UPDATE

After set `LogLevel=debug` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, I was able to have more data related to this issue. In `/var/log/messages/` I found this :

```
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111126] systemd[1]: -.mount changed dead -> mounted
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111147] systemd[1]: Activating default unit: default.target
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111153] systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job multi-user.target/start/replace
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111204] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit hpiwdt.service, ignoring: Unit hpiwdt.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status hpiwdt.service' for details.
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111276] systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on lwresd.service/start
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111279] systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to nss-lookup.target/start
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111281] systemd[1]: Walked on cycle path to lwresd.service/start
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111284] systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job nss-lookup.target/start
Jan 31 19:17:00 msx kernel:   10.111286] systemd[1]: Deleting job postfix.service/start as dependency of job nss-lookup.target/start
```

I don't even know what *is* or *does* `nss-lookup`.

Comment: Is AppArmor disabled?

Comment: Cross post: http://serverfault.com/q/837531/217116

Comment: Hi @shcherbak AppArmor is not running. I will edit my post. I have more data related to this issue when a set `LogLevel` from systemd with debug flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nss-lookup.target` is one of the optional `systemd` special targets. It is essentially acting as a virtual milestone in the boot process. Specifically, any system services that affect DNS lookup (like `lwresd` probably does) should specify in their `.service` file that they need to start **before** `nss-lookup.target`:

```
[Unit]
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
```

...and any services that need DNS resolution fully working before they can start can then specify that simply as:

```
[Unit]
After=nss-lookup.target
```

It might be that either the `lwresd` package did not quite follow this scheme, or that your custom distribution has an older version of `systemd` where there is some reason to use `Requires=` instead of `Wants=` which is the current recommended way.

When systemd detects an ordering conflict (an "ordering cycle") in its configuration, it resolves it in a very mechanical way, which is not always optimal in the grand scheme of things. In this case, the problem was in ordering between `lwresd` and `nss-lookup.target`, but Postfix got skipped in the process as collateral damage.

Since `nss-lookup.target` is optional, setting it as a `Requires=` dependency for Postfix is too strong and might cause problems... exactly like the one you had.

Comment: Very good information. Thank you. I mark as an answer since you were able to explain and point me out what is my potential problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, adding `LogLevel=debug` on `/etc/systemd/system.conf` provides useful log to understand what really happens on services at startup runtime. As mentioned in my  updated question, there's was an order conflit with `nss-lookup.target`. By removing `nss-lookup.target` directly in `/etc/systemd/system/postfix.service` in both variables`[Requires]` and `[After]` the system was able to start `postfix` on boot process.